# Return Double Complex Array in MEX file (Matlab)

Tags: c++, c, matlab, mex

I have a problem with MEX files in C/C++ coding.
I need to return a double complex array to Matlab but I am not able to do that and I don't find information about it. I show my code with some tries:

```
double complex output[nSymb];
nlhs = 1;
plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(nSymb,(mwSize)nlhs,mxCOMPLEX);

// 1º option
plhs[0] = output;
// 2º option
memcpy(plhs, output, nSymb * sizeof(double complex));
// 3º option
plhs = output;
```

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: I don't know MEX, but in C++, I'd expect the type `std::complex<double>` to be used. Also, `memcpy` has the destination argument _first_ and the source _second_. The name `output` suggests that you've swapped them. Also, `plhs[0]` gets assign twice in your code. Why? Finally, `plhs = output;` after the `memcpy`? This looks really confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned C++, so I've shown an example copying a `std::vector<double>` into an `MxArray` object, same can be applied to C-style arrays:

```
mxArray* CreateDoubleArray(const std::vector<double>& d)
{
    mxArray* m = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(d.size(), 1, mxComplexity::mxReal); // mxComplexity::mxCOMPLEX 
    double* pm = mxGetDoubles (m); // mxGetComplexDoubles
    
    for (size_t i=0; i<d.size(); i++)
    {
        pm[i] = d[i];
    }
    
    return m;
}

// ...
// Return value for the Mex:
plhs[0] = CreateDoubleArray(stdVecObj);
```

You can change the `value_type` of the vector to `std::complex`, and apply the changes suggested in the comments to handle complex type instead of double. `mxGetComplexDoubles` returns a `MxDOUBLE_CLASS*` [documented here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxclassid.html) (it's just a struct with a real and imaginary component of type mxDouble).